# Getting MCLR error in Proteus on PIC18 in a really simple circuit

Tags: pic, proteus

I'm simulating this circuit below in Proteus 8.1. It basically consists of a switch that, when pressed should send a signal to port A, and then port B should light a LED.

[image: Schematic]

I am using PIC18F4550, and the exact error I am getting is: `$MCLR$ is low processor is in reset`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information. For starters, how about a schematic of your circuit? And what software are you using that prints out that message?

Comment: I am using proteus 8.1, this is my circuit http://imgur.com/06UprRP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you don't have power connected to the processor.  You also left the PGM pin floating.

Since nothing is connected to the oscillator pins, you have to make sure the processor is configured to run from the internal oscillator.

Otherwise, a 10 kΩ pullup on MCLR to Vdd is fine.